Is it official Christian knowledge that the evil cannot create anything new?
This quote is attributed to J.R.R. Tolkien:

Evil cannot create anything new, they can only corrupt and ruin what good forces have invented or made.

and clarified here that it is only a paraphrase from Tolkien's work.
While the statement above is beautiful, and by my personal judgment entirely true, I am interested to know of there is any official statement (preferably in the Holy Bible, or some other very "strong" source) which conceives the same information.
Without a proper foundation, this quote has little to no value, except maybe artistic, sentimental, motivational...

Theologically, this idea has a long tradition. Augustine in the 4th century argued that evil was not a separate reality in opposition to the good; rather it was a lack of that which is good.

@PeterKirkpatrick: Your statement kind of proves that Satan does not exist :) The question, as wel las the original statement is about the beings, not about principles or philosophies. As in "the dark does not exist, it is just the absence of light".

It honestly depends on what you mean by "create".

Ex Nihilo? No, only God can do that.
New via Corruption? Yes, God can never do that. (It would be sin)

From an Orthodox understanding, we know that God did not create "Sin", He also did not create death.

God did not make death, and takes no pleasure in the destruction of any living thing; He created all things that they might have being (Wisdom of Solomon 1.13).


For I have no pleasure in the death of anyone, says the Lord God; so turn and live (Ezek 18.32).


Death is the result of sin. It is the final victory of the devil, the result of his destructive activity. If man had not sinned, he would not have died. His body may have changed and evolved over great periods of time, but it would not have been separated from his spirit to return to the dust, and man’s soul itself would not have been corrupted, losing power over its body and becoming its slave. This is the meaning of the sin of Adam, that man has emerged on the face of the earth, made in God’s image and inspired with His Spirit, and has chosen death instead of life, evil instead of righteousness, and so through defilement of his nature in rebellion against God, brought corruption and death to the world (cf. Gen 3, Rom 5.12–21). (Orthodox Church of America)

Of note is that the devil and his angels (the demons), are woefully (as in embarrassingly) unable to do much of anything. Consider that they can only go out to kill "with express permission" from God. (See the book of Job)
Another thing is that while demons can tempt us... they can't even be "too unfair" to us. As God promised to never allow us more temptation then we can withstand. (See 1 Corinthians 10:13)

For Christians, as for all men, death remains a tragedy. When confronted by death, like all men, and like Jesus Himself and His apostles, Christians can only mourn and weep (cf. Jn 11.35, Mt 26.37–38, Mk 14.33–34, Lk 22.42–44, Acts 8.2). But for Christians, filled with faith in Christ and His Father, the tragedy of death can be transformed into victory. (Ibid)


Short Answer: The Devil can barely do much of anything, he cannot create ex nihilo, he can corrupt things. This makes the quote you posted essentially based on a Christian understanding of the powers of darkness.

The devil "creating" something new only by corruption is entirely consistent with Tolkien's views, in fact that's exactly the claim he's making at that point in the book.

"Adam [...] has chosen death instead of life" - That seems to be at least a very liberal statement. According to my understanding, Adam merely chose to not have an argument with his wife - hoping that God would me more forgiving - and that was because he did not have the understanding of the chain of consequences of his act. Since the tree was metaphorical, the death could be metaphorical too, right? And there in the Garden, Adam did not have the experience of death. How could he actually understand his "choice" and its effects?

@virolino isn't really on topic with the question. Perhaps ask the question if it isn't already asked? I feel like I've answered or had an answer with more details about original/ancestral sin somewhere...

@Wyrsa: Don't worry, I did not complain about the answer. Just that a detail seems off.

The Biblical focus is less on the inability of evil to create, and more on creation as an attribute of God, but logically one follows from the other. John 1 seems to fit:

1 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
2 The same was in the beginning with God.
3 All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.

See also Colossians 1:16, for example. Regarding evil, the strongest text I can think of is John 10:10:

The thief cometh not, but for to steal, and to kill, and to destroy: I am come that they might have life, and that they might have it more abundantly.


"and without him was not any thing made that was made" - I temporarily forgot about this, tnx. However, it does not exclude the possibility that someone else might / could be able to create without "corruption".

@virolino doesn't it? Both this verse and the other I referenced are very clear about creation being the exclusive action of God. If nothing was made without God, who is the antithesis of evil, then it follows by simple logic that evil has no part in the act of creation.
